# Save UIImage to iPhone camera roll "as it is", RGB values must remain the same! (Swift)

Tags: iphone, swift, uiimage, rgb, camera-roll

I'm trying to save a UIImage from my App to the iPhone camera roll, but I noticed that when I save the image as JPEG or PNG the RGB values of my pixels are changed. I need to save the UIImage to the iPhone and then I need to import that image back into my App, and I need the new imported image to be EXACTLY the same as the one already in my App (same RGB values!). How can I do that? Is there a way to save my image from the App to the iPhone maintaining the same RGB values?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Why are you saving and then reimporting? And how are you saving and getting the image? Any time you encode the image there could be a lossy conversion if you aren't careful..

Comment: @Wain Thanks for your reply! I tried saving the image to camera roll as UIImage using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()` or `UIActivityViewController()` or as Data using `UIImagePNGRepresentation`or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and then `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`, but every time the RGB values in the saved image slightly differ from the RGB values in the original image and I assume that happens because the conversion is lossy... How can I save the image as it is, without any compression? Also, I get the image with `imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

Comment: What you want can't be done. Your image gets saved as a JPG in the photo album. JPG is a lossy format.